# Retrieve GridView string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView -

```
<asp:GridView ID="table_example" Runat="server" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
ClientIDMode="Static" onprerender="table_example_PreRender">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select"></asp:Label>

     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxPN_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="profileID" DataField="profileID" 
                        SortExpression="profileID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="profileName" DataField="profileName" 
                        SortExpression="profileName"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Where the code behind for `chkRow`-

```
protected void CheckBoxPN_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer; 

        //when a user clicks the checkbox I need the string from profileName in that row. 

    }
```

On debugging I can get to the checkBox changed event, however need to retrieve the string from the `profileName` cell from its respective row cell.

I tried something like this -

```
string c = row.Cells("profileName").value.toString();
```

However this did not work, how can I get the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a `BoundField` you need to use `Cells[index].Text`. Since it's in the third column:

```
string profileName = row.Cells[2].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give like

Ex :
you can straight away give like ;

```
string profilename = gridview.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;
```

Comment: actually i dint notice the previous answer.